# WIP tag change and synonyms

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, tags, tag-synonyms

We current have only one WIP-related tag: [wip-limits](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wip-limits). Personally, I'd prefer to see this changed to [work-in-progress](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-in-progress) for clarity. I'd also like to see some synonyms for [work-in-progress](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-in-progress) like:

- [wip](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wip)
- [wip-limits](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wip-limits)

Apparently, I don't have the mojo to shuffle tags around like that--diamond moderators to the rescue!--but since we only have a single [wip-limits](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wip-limits) question right now, it might be a good time to make the change if we think it's a good idea.

Opinions? Thoughts? Flames of any kind?

Comment: I don't see any reason why this is a bad idea, but I'll add the featured tag for this to push it to the community bulletin board to see if anyone else has an opinion. If you don't hear anything in a few days, feel free to flag the post with that wip-limits tag.  Also, you could remove that wip-limits and create work-in-progress yourself, since it's the only tag. Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Status

Apparently, I created the [work-in-progress](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-in-progress) tag, but I don't have enough answers in the tag category to create sensible synonyms yet. This will require moderator intervention in the future, if enough related tags needs to be rolled together (see [answer by @jmort253](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/a/595/4271)).

### Question is Mis-Tagged

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) is actually wrong; this should have been marked [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) since the synonyms have been deferred, but only moderators can change status tags.

Comment: Oops, good call!  Tag fixed. :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't create the synonyms, simply because there's only one question with this tag. Thus, creating synonyms really wouldn't be helpful as no one appears to be using these tags.

If this changes and we get more of these questions, feel free to bring this up in the future if we get a significant number of these types of questions.

Comment: If you'll note that you created the work-in-progress tag itself, I'll mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: Hmmm, actually, it looks like you created it. ;)  http://pm.stackexchange.com/posts/8507/revisions